# killing docker container when killing dotnet process

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-container

I am running a docker container with dotnet base image, I want to kill the whole container after 10 min. I thought if i kill the dotnet process with:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

it should kill the container as it was the process that started container but it's not working. Can someone please tell me what's the best way of killing container after some spesific time?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's traditional Linux docker (I'm unfamiliar with docker on Windows Server), then you should be able to stop the container by killing the process with pid 1.

Comment: yes, I killed the process but container is still alive, it just killed the dotnet process, my question is how to kill the container :)

Comment: With PID 1? Process.GetCurrentProcess(), or Something like Process.GetProcessByID(1) (the latter being pseudo code since I haven't used .Net a lot)?